# Added IOS QuickLook framework to react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Is a way to use IOS QuickLook framework in react-native? I read the documentation, but found only for widgets or components integration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to the **Peek and Pop** gesture that is part of 3D Touch on iOS. React Native doesn't currently support this out of the box. However, there is a [closed issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3113) on the react-native project discussing adding this feature, and here is a [working but incomplete Peek and Pop solution](https://github.com/brentvatne/PeekPopAttempt).

Comment: No, my question wasn't about 3D Touch gestures. I'm looking for any way of implementing QLPreviewController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController to preview files like when I open attachment in Mail. Is it possible to activate this screen through React Native?

Comment: Well, I feel a little silly now. Unfortunately (and obviously), I don't have any experience integrating the iOS QuickLook Framework in React Native. Good luck!